# Set UserAgent (cypress.json) is not reflected while running tests in Cypress

Tags: user-interface, mobile, automation, cypress, user-agent

I have set the following userAgent in cypress.json file but when i run the test...userAgent changes are not reflected and test runs on firefox/chrome browser as usual. I don't see any userAgent related browser changes during the run....meaning there is no difference in test run before and after setting user Agent. My laptop details: MacBook Pro (13 inch, 2017 model)

Values tried:

Mobile/Tablet:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Android 4.4; Mobile; rv:41.0) Gecko/41.0 Firefox/41.0
Mozilla/5.0 (Android 4.4; Tablet; rv:41.0) Gecko/41.0 Firefox/41.0
```

Desktop:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X x.y; rv:42.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/42.0
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X x.y; rv:10.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0
```

cypress.json

```
{
    "pluginsFile": "cypress/plugins/index.ts",
    "supportFile": "cypress/support/index.ts",
    "$schema": "https://on.cypress.io/cypress.schema.json",
    "viewportWidth": 1440,
    "viewportHeight": 900,
    "userAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X x.y; rv:10.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0",

    "chromeWebSecurity": false,
    "defaultCommandTimeout": 10000,

    "screenshotsFolder": "./build/brazil-cypress-tests/screenshots",
    "videosFolder": "./build/brazil-cypress-tests/videos",
    "videoCompression": 32,
    "requestTimeout": 15000,

    "reporter": "mocha-multi-reporters",
    "reporterOptions": {
        "configFile": "reporterConfig.json"
    },

    "retries": {
        "runMode": 1,
        "openMode": 1
    }
}
```

Did anyone encounter this issue? How do we set userAgent value in cypress tests? This is blocking my automation for different platforms.

**Additional Information:**
Also tried to set userAgent through cli/script but no luck.

```
  "cy:sample-script": "cypress open --config userAgent=\"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X x.y; rv:42.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/42.0\""
```

Comment: Is your web application a Public app, then I could give it a try, as your configs looks OK.

Comment: Here is the URL to my web application in US:  https://www.amazon.com/mc. or simply https://www.amazon.com will also do.